# Animating things framerate independent

Tags: java

I want to animate some text thats in an arraylist that gets changed often but I can't figure out how to animate it on the Y-Axis as it needs to move up and down and I've only set it up for `obj.renderY += 10 * deltaTime` but I need it to smoothly animate to the position wanted without overcomplciating it.

The current setup for animating the Y-Axis of the text is `obj.renderY = (obj.renderY * (speed - 1) + offset) / speed` and this is frame dependent and I haven't figured out how I would implement deltaTime into it properly most of the times I've tried it just breaks it. This current setup I have animates it to the position I want it to be on the Y-Axis even if its above or below the wanted position.

The offset is just equal to `2 + count * (fontHeight + 1)` I don't know if that would help but sure I'll include it anyway. Thanks for taking your time and reading this post.

Example of trying to animate the texts movement:

```
float speed = 14;
obj.renderY = (obj.renderY * (speed - 1) + offset) / speed
```

The class that is used to get deltaTime (Updates every frame):

```
public class Time {

    public static float deltaTime = 0;
    private static long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

    public static void update() {
        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        deltaTime = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000000000.0F;
        lastTime = currentTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you put the whole code so we can try it as well?

Comment: distance = speed * time so you need something like `renderY = renderY + speed * deltaTime`

Comment: @tgdavies That literally does the same thing as `renderY += 10 * deltaTime` and again I said it needs to be able to move up and down smoothly without being effect by the frame rate and I don't want to use a lot of if statements to check if its below or above the wanted Y Position to add or subtract the renderY

Comment: Using `deltaTime` means it isn't affected by the frame rate, assuming that you call `update()` correctly.

Comment: Use the offset to initialise renderY, don't add it each time. You are going to have to use an if statement to decide if you have reached the edge of the area you want to move in.

Comment: @tgdavies Can't really figure out how to implement it into my hold method which is `obj.renderY = (obj.renderY * (speed - 1) + offset) / speed` and I know deltaTime works because I use it for other things but I actually cannot figure out how to implement it into that method it breaks everytime not even (speed * Time.deltaTime) which looks like it would work but I probably completely wrong. I have math that checks if its roughly in the location I want it to be in which then stops the animation completely until the arraylist is modified  then it animates to account for that change.

Answer (score 0):

Use [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html). It was literally built to solve this exact problem.

[`Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,java.awt.event.ActionListener))

- **delay** - Place the amount of time you want the timer to wait before kicking things off. Please note - this does ***NOT*** mean the amount of time between each task, only the amount of time before ***starting*** each task.
- **listener** - Place your actual task here.

Then, all you need to do is use the [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html#start()) method, and that should be it. You can configure the timer in other ways, but that is the basics.

**EDIT** - I imagine that many people who are asking this question are game developers trying to make some part of their game run at 60 frames per second.

You ***can*** use a timer, but you might be better off using something from a game engine instead.

In short, you probably want something more feature rich than a simple timer. Timers are effective, but they can be hard to manage, and may not kick off at the ***exact*** frame that you want them to, leading to issues. Timers are meant to be a simple tool to make kicking off a task at a certain frequency easier. But it's rarely as simple as that when making a game.

I would discourage you from using this timer for anything other than a basic repetitive task that only needs to start and stop after a certain event. If you want something with precision, stick to using the tools found in some of your game engines. They specialize in getting certain actions to kick off at the exact times you want them to.

Comment: I just want the text to animate at the same speed no matter what the fps is which is why I'm using deltaTime

Comment: Then my solution is exactly what you need. Use a swing timer to animate the text and it should work out exactly as you expect, just be mindful of the performance.

Comment: I want to specifically use deltaTime for this because I want it to still look good and not have it so it just renders at 60 fps while everything else renders at 120 fps as an example so deltaTime would be a better method for rendering what I want smoothly.

Comment: @RareHyperIon You do understand that my solution is using `deltaTime`, right?

Comment: Yes but like I said before I want to implement it into a single line of code like I could do with my old method but the old one is faster/slower depending on the framerate of the game. If I knew how to implement the deltaTime into the single line of code I would've done that but apparently with deltaTime I can't really do single line to adjust it if its below or above the wanted position as it just breaks each and every time which means I have to do if statements to check if its above or below the wanted Y value and checking if its roughly equal to the value to prevent bouncing.